# Как импортировать набор статики из npm_modules в angular2 проект

Tags: angular2, angular-cli

Собственно есть проект на angular2 инициализированный через CLI. Как сконфигурировать angular, что бы при сборке подтягивались CSS/img из некоего модуля в node_modules?

Comment: `import '../node_modules/module/dist/styles.css'`, Вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: Мне нужно не только CSS, но и все картинки и шрифты

Comment: это не ангуляр надо конфигурировать а сборщик тогда. Причем тут ангуляр вообще? Это же external зависимости будут. Сборщиком webpack/gulp задайте пути того, где и каких расширений надо собирать/оптимизировать и собрать и т.д.

Comment: Да, это я уже понял